# EntityFieldQuery: Load all revisions

Tags: entities, nodes, database

I have a self-defined entity with revisions called `command`. The instance with `id=1` has 3 revisions. Now I want to load all these revisions. Tried this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'command')
  ->propertyCondition('id', 1)
  ->age(FIELD_LOAD_REVISION)
  ;
$result = $query->execute();
```

but it gives me still only one revision, the current one. There's no difference to calling it without `->age(FIELD_LOAD_REVISION)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you cycling through all the results? i.e. `$query->fetchAll();`

Comment: Just thought "OMG, right!" But then adding `$result = $result->fetchAll();` to the code above just gave me the error `Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object`. And it seems that `EntityFieldQuery` [doesn't have a fetch function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just drop the `execute()` and do `$result = $query->fetchAll()`

Comment: OK, so tried that code
    `$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'command')->propertyCondition('id', 1)->age(FIELD_LOAD_REVISION);
    $result = $query->fetchAll();`
and still got `Call to undefined method...`. Maybe you're mixing it up with `db_select()`?

Comment: I also can't get this working...

Comment: @pcambra's solution works.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:** Use a regular query instead of a EntityFieldQuery to load all entity revisions.

**Explanation:**

In the age function on entity.inc there's this comment:

> Blockquote
>      * Note that this only affects field conditions. Property conditions always
>      * apply to the current revision.

So as long as you provide a **property condition**, you will get only the last revision id. If you query with **fieldCondition**, you will get the revisions, as the age method is actually querying the field revision table and not the node revision one (field_sql_storage.module):

```
  else {
    $tablename_function = '_field_sql_storage_revision_tablename';
    $id_key = 'revision_id';
  }
```

Otherwise, the entity table is queried so it will always return the entities and not the revisions.

You could do a [addTag](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3aaddTag/7) and modify the query object there but at this point the modifications will be so big that it's actually better to do a regular query instead.

Example using generic info for the entity and entity api entity_revision_load.

```
  $entity_type = 'command';
  $value = 1;
  $entity_info = entity_get_info($entity_type);

  $query = db_select($entity_info['revision table'], 'revision');
  $query->fields('revision', array($entity_info['entity keys']['id'], $entity_info['entity keys']['revision']))
    ->condition('revision.' . $entity_info['entity keys']['id'], $value);
  $revisions = $query
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssoc($entity_info['entity keys']['revision']);

  $entities = array();
  foreach ($revisions as $key => $revision) {
    $entities[] = entity_revision_load($entity_type, $key);
  }
```